# Need help in c programming

Tags: c, printf

I have a question about the following program,I am unable to understand the output of the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    char c='1';
    clrscr();
    printf("%d",&c);
    getch();
}
```

In my compiler it is printing "-11" and i am using Turbo C++.I know that if i use "`c`" instead of "`&c`" it will print 49 because it is a ASCII number of '1'.But why it is printing -11 when i use "`&c`".

Comment: As for why `&c` is "negative", see [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: Enable all warnings and see. And you shouldn't use Turbo C anyway, it's even older and the oldest C standard

Comment: Reading a C programming book beforehand is better

Answer (score 5):

`&c` denotes the address of `c`, not its value, and has a pointer type. Using `%d` for a pointer has [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so your program is free to print whatever it likes (or indeed do something entirely different instead).

What likely is happening in practice is that the pointer is getting reinterpreted as an integer, and the integer happens to have its top bit set. In [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) this represents a negative number, so it is getting printed as such.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `printf` line to:

```
printf("%c",c);
```

In your code, `%d` is printing the signed decimal integer, not the char value. However, here it is undefined, since;

`&c` is the address of `c`, not the value.

You can find more specifiers on: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: _'is printing the signed decimal integer'_ Of what in the OPs sample?

Answer (score 1):

You output the address of `c` as an integer.

If you want to output the value of `c` as an integer, using `printf("%d", c);`; to output it as a character, using `printf("%c", c);`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `&c` is the address of the charater `c` not the value of it. Do not put the `&` there if you want to see its value. In Turbo C It is perfectly valid to print out the address as an integer, however a Decent compiler will warn you:

> warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char*’